# quickfix SocketInitiator has no response and no exception

Tags: sockets, quickfix

I'm trying to connect to a ForexTrading broker FIX API and do some trading.

I tried my best to read through the Quickfix for .net. and almost understand the process of how the quickfix works.  However, when I try to initiate the socketinitiator, I failed to do that and there are no complaints and exceptions from VS 2012. It is simply stuck there.

Here's my code:

```
private void iFind_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        QuickFix.SessionSettings settings = new QuickFix.SessionSettings("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\My Box Files(shewenhao@hotmail.com)\\Work With Mr.Liu\\ForexAutoTradingSystem\\ForexAutoTradingSystem\\integralfix.cfg");

        IntegralFixAPI integralFixAPIApplication = new IntegralFixAPI();

        QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new QuickFix.FileStoreFactory(settings);

        QuickFix.ILogFactory logFactory = new QuickFix.ScreenLogFactory(settings);

        QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator initiator = new QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator(
            integralFixAPIApplication, storeFactory, settings, logFactory);

        MessageBox.Show(settings.ToString());
        integralFixAPIApplication.MyInitiator = initiator;

        initiator.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            MessageBox.Show("true");
        }

        //initiator.Stop();
    }
    catch (System.Exception systeme)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(systeme.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(systeme.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

You may notice that I have a MessageBox right below the SocketInitiator and it pops up before this QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator line. I do not get it that why I failed at this point. On the page of quickfix .Net http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/creating-an-application, it says that you simply need to replace the threadedacceptor with the socketinitiator. However, I can not pass through this initiation line.

Comment: Did you know this website has a feature that lets you post your code as text?  That would make it so much easier for us.

Comment: @JohnZwinck here you go. Thank you for your help:)